# Regular Expression in Javascript for restricting two numerals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to restrict upto two numerals after decimal points, but i have to allow some special characters, how can we do that,

Ex:

```
123.12%

345463543.12$
```

The character may be units/metrics it may have special characters as well as alphabets accompanied with that

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is it always going to be a number followed by exactly one special character?

Comment: say the character may be units/metrics it may have special characters as well as alphabets accompanied with that

Comment: I updated my answer with your new requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/A-Za-z]?
```

You can test it [here](https://regexr.com/40a5l)

---

@evolutionxbox Here's an explanation of each of the parts:

```
[0-9]+
```

Checks for at least 1 number

```
(\.[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Decimal numbers

```
[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/A-Za-z]?
```

Allows for special character and alphabetical characters

Comment: What does this do? Can you break it apart and explain it?